# Tables: how to eliminate whitespace in cells? And how to center a cell vertically?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I did the table below (it is in Portuguese) but I could not eliminate some spaces and center 2 cells ... see the attached figure to understand. I need to save space on the text!

Tanks for help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Princípios Táticos do Jogo de Futebol}
\label{my-label}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{@{}cclc@{}}
\toprule
Princípios\\    Gerais                                                                                           & Tentar Criar superioridade numérica                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{Evitar a igualdade numérica}              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Não permitir a inferioridade numérica}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \midrule

 Fases                                                                                                              & \textbf{Ataque (com posse de bola)}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & \multirow{12}{*}{\begin{turn}{-90}\Huge Transição Defesa-ataque e/ou Ataque-defesa\end{turn}} & \textbf{Defesa (sem posse de bola)}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Princípios \\ Operacionais\end{tabular}                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}Conservar a bola;\\ Construir ações ofensivas;\\ Progredir pelo campo do jogo adversário;\\ Criar situações de finalização;\\ Finalizar a baliza adversária.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}Impedir a progressão do adversário;\\ Reduzir o espaço de jogo adversário;\\ Proteger a baliza;\\ Anular as situações de finalização;\\ Recuperar a bola.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
\multirow{10}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\begin{turn}{-90}\Huge Princípios Fundamentais\end{turn}\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Penetração}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            &                                                              & \textbf{Contenção}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
                                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Desestabilizar a organização adversária;\\ -- Atacar diretamente o adversário ou baliza;\\ -- Criar situações vantajosas para o ataque em\\ termos numéricos e espaciais.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &                                                              &  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Diminuir espaço de ação ofensiva do portador da bola;\\ -- Orientar a progressão do portador da bola;\\ -- Parar ou atrasar o ataque ou contra-ataque adversário;\\ -- Propiciar maior tempo para organização defensiva;\\ -- Restringir as possibilidades de passe a outro jogador adversário;\\ -- Evitar o drible que favoreça progressão pelo campo de jogo em direção ao gol;\\ -- Impedir a finalização à baliza.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
                                                                                                                 & \textbf{Cobertura Ofensiva}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &                                                              &  \textbf{Cobertura defensiva}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\
                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Dar apoio ao portador da bola oferecendo-lhe opções para a sequência do jogo;\\ -- Diminuir a pressão adversária sobre o portador da bola;\\ -- Criar superioridade numérica;\\ -- Criar desequílibrio na organização defensiva adversária;\\ -- Garantir a manutenção da posse de bola.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                        &                                                              &  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Servir de novo obstáculo ao portador da bola, caso esse passe pelo jogador de contenção;\\ -- Transmitir segurança e confiança ao jogador de contenção para que ele tenha iniciativa de combate às ações ofensivas do portador da bola;\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
                                                                                                                 & \textbf{Mobilidade}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            &                                                              & \textbf{Equilíbrio}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\
                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Criar ações de ruptura da organização defensiva adversária;\\ -- Apresentar-se em um espaço muito propício para a consecução do gol;\\ -- Criar linhas de passe em profundidade;\\ -- Conseguir o domínio da bola para dar sequência a ação ofensiva (passe ou finalização).\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Assegurar a estabilidade defensiva da região de disputa da bola;\\ -- Apoiar os companheiros que executam as ações de contenção e cobertura defensiva;\\ -- Cobrir eventuais linhas de passe;\\ -- Marcar potenciais jogadores que podem receber a bola;\\ -- Fazer recuperação defensiva sobre o portador da bola;\\ -- Recuperar ou afastar a bola da zona onde ela se encontra.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
                                                                                                                 & \textbf{Espaço}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                &                                                              & \textbf{Concentração}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\
                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Utilizar e ampliar o espaço de jogo efetivo da equipe;\\ -- Expandir as distâncias/posicionamentos entre os jogadores adversários;\\ -- Dificultar as ações de marcação da equipe adversária;\\ -- Facilitar as ações ofensivas da equipe;\\ -- Movimentar para um espaço de menor pressão;\\ -- Ganhar "tempo" para tomar a decisão correta para dar sequência no jogo;\\ -- Procurar opções mais seguras, através dos jogadores posicionados mais defensivamente, para dar sequência ao jogo.\end{tabular}} &                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Aumentar a proteção ao gol;\\ -- Condicionar o jogo ofensivo adversário para zonas de menor risco do campo de jogo;\\ -- Propiciar aumento de pressão no centro do jogo.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4} 
                                                                                                                 & \textbf{Unidade Ofensiva}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      &                                                              & \textbf{Unidade defensiva}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Facilitar o deslocamento da equipe para o campo de jogo adversário;\\ -- Permitir a equipe atacar em unidade ou em bloco;\\ -- Oferecer mais segurança as ações ofensivas realizadas no centro do jogo;\\ -- Propiciar que mais jogadores se posionem no centro do jogo;\\ -- Diminuir o espaço de jogo no campo defensivo.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                     &                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}p{4cm}}-- Permitir a equipe defender em unidade ou em bloco;\\ -- Garantir estabilidade espacial e sincronia dinâmica entre as linhas longitudinais e transversais da equipe em ações ofensivas;\\ -- Diminuir a amplitude ofensiva da equipe adversária na sua largura e profundidade;\\ -- Assegurar linhas orientadoras básicas que influenciam as atitudes e os comportamentos tático-técnicos dos jogadores que se posicionam fora do centro de jogo;\\ -- Equilibrar ou reequilibrar constantemente a repartição de forças da organização defensiva consoante às situações momentâneas de jogo;\\ -- Reduzir o espaço de jogo utilizando a regra do impedimento;\\ -- Obstruir  possíveis linhas de passe para jogadores que se encontram  fora do centro de jogo;\\ -- Possibilitar a participação em uma ação defensiva subsequente;\\ -- Propiciar que mais jogadores se posicionem no centro de jogo.\end{tabular}} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-4} 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**warning:**
all white space is not possible to remove: the foutg column is higher than second. consequently there will always be an empty space below the second column.

- vertical spaces in cells arise because the cell haven't equal height. this can be remove, if in second and fourth column insert tables with own row divisions
- table is huge, without changing page layout it cannot be fit on one page
- to exploit all text width i use `tabularx` table environment. this allow me to increase font size from `\tiny` to `\scriptsize`
- for items in cell i suggest to use `itemize` environment as defined by package `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=25mm]
            {geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell,
            multirow,
            tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\renewcommand\cellrotangle{-90}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,wide}
    \centering
\caption{Princípios Táticos do Jogo de Futebol}
\label{my-label}
    \scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c L c L @{}}
    \toprule
\makecell[bc]{Princípios\\ Gerais}
    & \makecell[bc]{Tentar Criar\\ superioridade numérica}
        & \makecell[bc]{Evitar a\\ igualdade\\ numérica}
            & \makecell[bc]{Não permitir a\\ inferioridade numérica}    \\
    \midrule
Fases
    & \thead{Ataque (com posse de bola)}
        & \multirow{66}{*}{\rotatebox{-90}{\Huge Transição Defesa-ataque e/ou Ataque-defesa}}
            & \thead{Defesa (sem posse de bola)}                        \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
\makecell[l]{Princípios \\ Opera-\\ cionais}
    & \makecell[l]{Conservar a bola;\\
                   Construir ações ofensivas;\\
                   Progredir pelo campo do jogo adversário;\\
                   Criar situações de finalização;\\
                   Finalizar a baliza adversária.}
        &   & \makecell[l]{Impedir a progressão do adversário;\\
                           Reduzir o espaço de jogo adversário;\\
                           Proteger a baliza;\\
                           Anular as situações de finalização;\\
                           Recuperar a bola.}                           \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
\rotatebox[origin=r]{-90}{\Huge Princípios Fundamentais}
    & \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\linewidth}@{}}
        \thead{Penetração}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Desestabilizar a organização adversária;
    \item Atacar diretamente o adversário ou baliza;
    \item Criar situações vantajosas para o ataque em termos numéricos e espaciais.
    \end{itemize}   \\
    \midrule
        \thead{Cobertura Ofensiva}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Dar apoio ao portador da bola oferecendo-lhe opções para a sequência do jogo;
    \item Diminuir a pressão adversária sobre o portador da bola;
    \item Criar superioridade numérica;
    \item Criar desequílibrio na organização defensiva adversária;
    \item Garantir a manutenção da posse de bola.
    \end{itemize}   \\
    \midrule
        \thead{Mobilidade}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Criar ações de ruptura da organização defensiva adversária;
    \item Apresentar-se em um espaço muito propício para a consecução do gol;
    \item Criar linhas de passe em profundidade;
    \item Conseguir o domínio da bola para dar sequência a ação ofensiva (passe ou finalização).
    \end{itemize}   \\
    \midrule
        \thead{Espaço}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Utilizar e ampliar o espaço de jogo efetivo da equipe;
    \item Expandir as distâncias/posicionamentos entre os jogadores adversários;
    \item Dificultar as ações de marcação da equipe adversária;
    \item Facilitar as ações ofensivas da equipe;
    \item Movimentar para um espaço de menor pressão;
    \item Ganhar "tempo" para tomar a decisão correta para dar sequência no jogo;
    \item Procurar opções mais seguras, através dos jogadores posicionados mais defensivamente, para dar sequência ao jogo.
        \end{itemize}   \\
    \midrule
        \thead{Unidade Ofensiva}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Facilitar o deslocamento da equipe para o campo de jogo adversário;
    \item Permitir a equipe atacar em unidade ou em bloco;
    \item Oferecer mais segurança as ações ofensivas realizadas no centro do jogo;
    \item Propiciar que mais jogadores se posionem no centro do jogo;
    \item Diminuir o espaço de jogo no campo defensivo.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
        &   &   \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\linewidth}@{}}
                \thead{Contenção}                                         \\
           \begin{itemize}
           \item Diminuir espaço de ação ofensiva do portador da bola;
           \item Orientar a progressão do portador da bola;
           \item Parar ou atrasar o ataque ou contra-ataque adversário;
           \item Propiciar maior tempo para organização defensiva;
           \item Restringir as possibilidades de passe a outro jogador adversário;
           \item Evitar o drible que favoreça progressão pelo campo de jogo em direção ao gol;
           \item Impedir a finalização à baliza.
           \end{itemize}    \\
           \midrule
                \thead{Cobertura defensiva}
           \begin{itemize}
           \item Servir de novo obstáculo ao portador da bola, caso esse passe pelo jogador de contenção;
           \item Transmitir segurança e confiança ao jogador de contenção para que ele tenha iniciativa de combate às ações ofensivas do portador da bola;
           \end{itemize}    \\
           \midrule
                \thead{Equilíbrio}
           \begin{itemize}
           \item Assegurar a estabilidade defensiva da região de disputa da bola;
           \item Apoiar os companheiros que executam as ações de contenção e cobertura defensiva;
           \item Cobrir eventuais linhas de passe;
           \item Marcar potenciais jogadores que podem receber a bola;
           \item Fazer recuperação defensiva sobre o portador da bola;
           \item Recuperar ou afastar a bola da zona onde ela se encontra.
           \end{itemize}    \\
           \midrule
                \thead{Concentração}
           \begin{itemize}
           \item Aumentar a proteção ao gol;
           \item Condicionar o jogo ofensivo adversário para zonas de menor risco do campo de jogo;
           \item Propiciar aumento de pressão no centro do jogo.
           \end{itemize}    \\
           \midrule
                \thead{Unidade defensiva}
           \begin{itemize}
           \item Permitir a equipe defender em unidade ou em bloco;
           \item Garantir estabilidade espacial e sincronia dinâmica entre as linhas longitudinais e transversais da equipe em ações ofensivas;
           \item Diminuir a amplitude ofensiva da equipe adversária na sua largura e profundidade;
           \item Assegurar linhas orientadoras básicas que influenciam as atitudes e os comportamentos tático-técnicos dos jogadores que se posicionam fora do centro de jogo;
           \item Equilibrar ou reequilibrar constantemente a repartição de forças da organização defensiva consoante às situações momentâneas de jogo;
           \item Reduzir o espaço de jogo utilizando a regra do impedimento;
           \item Obstruir  possíveis linhas de passe para jogadores que se encontram  fora do centro de jogo;
           \item Possibilitar a participação em uma ação defensiva subsequente;
           \item Propiciar que mais jogadores se posicionem no centro de jogo.
           \end{itemize}
           \end{tabular}    \\
           \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, very nice... I did not know this way of doing tables! Thank you very much!!